# i get ORA-01722: invalid number error in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have problem about ora 01722 i have string prols it is like "1501,1701,1901,2001,2501,2601" or "2321,1331,111231,35501" and i want control table x' column x.rol_id include prols or not but i get error in my code. here is part of my code. thanks.

```
 function get_menu_detay_01(pmenu_kod      varchar2,
                             proller          varchar2) return sys_refcursor is
  v_cr_1 sys_refcursor;

      begin
        open v_cr_1 for
         select distinct mtd.sira_no,
                 mtd.seviye_1,
                 mtd.fa_icon_1,
                 mtd.seviye_2,
                 mtd.fa_icon_2,
                 mtd.seviye_3,
                 mtd.fa_icon_3,
                 ut.uygulama_tanim_id,
                 ut.aciklama,
                 ut.path,
                 ut.fa_icon,
                 ut.href,
                 ut.onclick
            from uat.menu_tanim_d mtd
            left join uat.uygulama_tanim ut
              on ut.uygulama_tanim_id = mtd.uygulama_tanim_id
           left join uat.uygulama_yetki uy 
             on mtd.uygulama_tanim_id = uy.uygulama_tanim_id  
           where mtd.menu_kod = pmenu_kod
           and uy.rol_id  in (select regexp_substr(tt.rol, '[^,]+', 1, level)
                            from (select proller rol
                                    from dual t) tt
                          connect by regexp_substr(tt.rol, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
           order by mtd.sira_no;

    return v_cr_1;
  end;
```

Comment: Why don't you insert those comma-seperated values into a table ? `select prols  rol from dual t` has no sense. Do you have to replace `prols` with such comma-seperated strings any time you need to run ..?

Answer (score 1):

If you say the strings you are splitting has separator `,` then you need to change the regular expression `[^,]+` to to include `,` instead `;` or the other way around

I just tried and its working,

```
WITH tst
AS
(SELECT 1501 rol_id FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1701 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1901 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2001 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2501 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2601 FROM dual
) 
SELECT * 
  FROM tst x
 WHERE x.rol_id  in (select regexp_substr(tt.rol, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
                            from (select '1701,1901,2001,2501,2601' rol
                                    from dual t) tt
                          connect by regexp_substr(tt.rol, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
```

---

**EDIT: Test with function** Please check how you call the function and pass the string in proper format or not

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_menu_detay_01(proller VARCHAR2)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
 v_cr_1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
 OPEN v_cr_1 FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   (  SELECT 1501 rol_id FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 1701 FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 1901 FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 2001 FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 2501 FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 2601 FROM dual
           ) x
    WHERE  x.rol_id IN (SELECT regexp_substr(tt.rol,'[^,)]+',1,LEVEL)
                        FROM   (SELECT proller rol FROM dual t) tt
                        CONNECT BY regexp_substr(tt.rol,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL);

  RETURN v_cr_1;
END get_menu_detay_01;
```

***Test:***

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
 lo_ref_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
 lo_number NUMBER;
BEGIN
  lo_ref_cur :=  get_menu_detay_01('1701,1901,2001,2501,2601');
  LOOP 
    FETCH lo_ref_cur INTO lo_number;
    EXIT WHEN lo_ref_cur%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(lo_number); 
  END LOOP;
END;
/
Output:
------
1701
1901
2001
2501
2601

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: sir my prols  is changeable it could be like '1501,12331,22201,25501,23301'.

Comment: Do you mean it could be with separator `,` or `;` ?

Comment: no i mean my string changeable. like "1501,1701,1901,2001,2501,2601" or "2321,1331,111231,35501" or "9801,1101,67001,254"

Comment: Yes that is fine. Your query is fine and you need to change the pattern as i did in my answer.

Comment: im already try but this time im waiting in executing... and there is no reponse.

Comment: Post the complete query you are executing ?

Comment: It should work, I don't see where you set the value for `prols` ? you try passing the value directly and check otherwise

Comment: i get invalid number error. you can check again my question and you will see prols.